# How do I create a color-coded comparison table based on the number of occurrences in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, compare

I compare the score given by two different raters to 850 patients. The score can be a whole number from 1 to 9. My dataframe consist of 2 colum,s (the two assessors) and 850 rows (one row per patient with the score from 1 to 9).

With the table() function, I did a table to compare the values given by the two assessors

```
table(df$score_assessor1, df$score_assessor2)
```

[image]

I recreated the table in Excel :

[image]

I'd like to have the same table but with a color-code for the number of occurences (for example white if = 0, yellow if 0 < x < 11, orange if 11 < x < 30 etc...)

Can anyone help me to plot such a table?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check out the [conditional formatting with kableExtra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#Conditional_logic)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a simple heatmap using `dplyr::count()` and ggplot2:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  count(
    score_assessor1 = factor(score_assessor1, levels = 1:9), 
    score_assessor2 = factor(score_assessor2, levels = 1:9),
    .drop = FALSE
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(score_assessor1, score_assessor2)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = n)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = n)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "YlOrRd", direction = 1) +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

(Conversion to factors and `.drop = FALSE` in `count()` make it so cells with no counts show as `0` instead of `NA`.)

*Example data:*

```
library(scales)
set.seed(13)

df <- data.frame(score_assessor1 = rnorm(300)) %>% 
  mutate(
    score_assessor2 = score_assessor1 + rnorm(300) * 5,
    across(everything(), ~ round(rescale(.x, c(1, 9))))
  )
```